# Using LESS & jQuery to switch body text color dependent on background color?

Tags: jquery, css, colors, less

I have a nice script which lets you change the background color of a site. As I am using LESS CSS, I'm able to adjust the color of different sections of the site. For example:

```
@bgcolor: #bad2e3;

body {
    background-color: @bgcolor;
}
.section {
    background-color: (darken(@bgcolor,10%);
}
```

When a user chooses a background color, I can simply call `less.refreshStyles();` and this works fine.

My problem is I need the body text to be change dependent on the background color. For example, a dark background color requires a light body text, and vice versa.

I could code this into the CSS, but this would mean specifying a body text color for each possible background color.

**Is there a function, either using the color functions available in LESS, or using jQuery, where I can detect the darkness of the background color and change the body text color if necessary?**

By way of example, [0to255.com](http://0to255.com/bad2e3) shows light/dark text dependent on the background color.

Comment: Sure, but I'm just using it as a visual example of what I'm asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns the background color of your body:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor
```

Edit: Sorry missunderstood the question. In this link [get color contrast](http://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast) you have a function to detect the contrast of a color in javascript:

```
function getContrastYIQ(hexcolor){
    var r = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(0,2),16);
    var g = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(2,2),16);
    var b = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(4,2),16);
    var yiq = ((r*299)+(g*587)+(b*114))/1000;
    return (yiq >= 128) ? 'light' : 'dark';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I'm asking. I can already get & change the background color. I want detect how dark the background color is, and use that to detect whether to serve a light or dark body text

Comment: Very true, there you have an edit to calculate the YIQ of a color

Answer (score 4):

As Fernando said, you have to calculate [YIQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ).

Here's a (LESS) function that I used for this purpose:

```
.getContrastYIQ(@color) when (iscolor(@color))
{
    .return_contrast_color(@yiq) when (@yiq >= 128) { color: #000; }
    .return_contrast_color(@yiq) when (@yiq < 128)  { color: #fff; }
    @r: red(@color);
    @g: green(@color);
    @b: blue(@color);
    @yiq: ((@r*299)+(@g*587)+(@b*114))/1000;
    .return_contrast_color(@yiq);
}
```

Usage:

```
@bgcolor: #bad2e3;
body {
    background-color: @bgcolor;
    .getContrastYIQ(@bgcolor);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Other alternative is `Guards` feature of LESS

> Guards are useful when you want to match on expressions, as opposed to simple values or arity. If you are familiar with functional programming, you have probably encountered them already.

That's more or less simular if/else conditions so using something like this (taken from official LESS source):

```
.mixin (@a) when (lightness(@a) >= 50%) {
  background-color: black;
}
.mixin (@a) when (lightness(@a) < 50%) {
  background-color: white;
}
.mixin (@a) {
  color: @a;
}
```

You could have benefits of dynamic CSS generation, and what's more important keep code more consistent

Answer (score 1):

You are probably asking for color contrast. There was a nice PHP tutorial for that a while ago, maybe you can abstract it to JavaScript: http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2008-09/18-calculating_color_contrast_with_php